# Multiple-tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

I'm sure this has been explained elsewhere, but I couldn't find anything that made complete sense to me.

I'm trying to use the os.walk() function in python, which returns a 3-tuple.  I now understand how to use it correctly (for x,y,z in os.walk()), but I'm still confused on the inner structure of the 3-tuple.  May not be wholly necessary to understand this but please humor me for my own sanity.

According to the documentation for os.walk, the 3-tuple response is of the form (rootdirname, list of sub dirs, list of files).  However, that only describes a single directory's data and not the sub directories'.

My question is, if the form of the entire object is actually:
A) a list of 3-item tuples (root1,subdirs1,files1), (root2, subdirs2, files2), ...

or

B) a tuple of 3 distinct lists ((root1,root2), (subdirs1, subdirs2), (files1, files2)), where just by tuple magic, all of the 1s are associated together, and all of the 2s are associated together.

Thanks for the help

**Edit:**
Thanks to Peter DeGlopper for the tip on the generator object.

The original question spawned because I was under the assumption that os.walk() returned a list of 3-tuples, but in fact it dynamically generates a single 3-tuple on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Specifically, it's a generator that yields 3-item tuples as it's evaluated (not a list).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about generators.  Now it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For each directory walked, you get a tuple of the path to that directory, the files in that directory, and the directories in that directory. The latter two are sequences (lists, but that doesn't matter). You use them like this:

```
for root, files, dirs in os.walk("/path/"):
    for filepath in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filepath)
        # process file
    for dirpath in dirs:
        dirpath = os.path.join(root, dirpath)
        # process dir
```